# boost::range to process content of a container and pipe to next process with values from a map

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have a map like `std::map<std::string,  std::vector<int> >`. I want to create one vector out of all the sub-vectors from values of the map. I can do it using the loops but I wanted to use the `boost::range` library where I can pipe the input of one transform to another so that the code is more readable and succinct. I tried something like below but needed some help to do it correctly.
Thank you

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct GetMapValue 
{
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    const T2& operator()( const std::pair<T1,T2>& key_val ) const
    { 
       return key_val.second;
    }
};

struct GetINTs 
{
    GetINTs(std::vector<int> aVec1)
    {
        aMyVec = aVec1;
    }
    void operator()( const std::vector<int>& val )
    { 
        aMyVec.insert( val.end(), val.begin(), aMyVec.end() );
    }
    private:
    std::vector<int> aMyVec;

};

int main(){

std::map<std::string,  std::vector<int> > x;
std::vector<int> y, z;

std::vector<int> temp;
temp.push_back(1);
temp.push_back(1);
x.insert(std::make_pair("one", temp));

temp.clear();
temp.push_back(2);
temp.push_back(2);
x.insert(std::make_pair("two", temp));

temp.clear();
temp.push_back(3);
temp.push_back(3);
x.insert(std::make_pair("three", temp));

boost::copy( x | boost::adaptors::transformed(GetMapValue),     std::back_inserter(y) );
boost::copy( y | boost::adaptors::transformed(GetINTs), std::back_inserter(z) );

}
```

Comment: Does `temp.push_back(1,1);` even compile?

Comment: With [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), it would be `auto ints = m | ranges::view::values | ranges::view::join;`

Comment: @NathanOliver There's a lot there that doesn't compile.

Comment: Rused it in the first place. Made it to compile now:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adaptor already exists and is called

- [`boost::adaptors::map_keys`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_keys.html)
- [`boost::adaptors::map_values`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html)

Here's a sample:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad765b699a330df2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > x {
        { "hello", { 1,2,3 } },
        { "world", { 4,5,6 } },
    };

    boost::copy(x | boost::adaptors::map_keys, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout << "Keys: ", " "));
    for (auto& vec : x | boost::adaptors::map_values)
        boost::copy(vec, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout << "\nValues: ", " "));
}
```

Prints

```
Keys: hello world 
Values: 1 2 3 
Values: 4 5 6
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to pipe the output of first boost::copy to get the final vector instead of using the for loop? Like                              boost:copy (x | boost::adaptors::map_values | boost:transform :: final_vector)

Comment: No. In such case, I'd use RangeV3 or use for_each: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be3ab5753d21dba8. Boost Range doesn't have flatten